# Fastest searching algorithm for 5 million records from linear search, binary search, b tree search algorithm?

Tags: data-structures, complexity-theory

If I have 5 million records, then which searching algorithm will be better from linear search, binary search, b tree search algorithm?

Comment: This question is too broad.  We need to know more about the structure and the content of your data.  What data structure is it in?  What is each element?

Comment: It depends on the structure of your data and how you are reading it.

Comment: Assume there are 5 millions rows , then how many iterations will be there for 1) Binary search algorithm 2) B-tree search algorithm.??

Answer (score 2):

Every data structure has it's value.

For instance, you'd use a binary tree most likely if you had numerically sorted data because your complexity would be really low (I.e. O(logn)).

You would use a linear search only if you have a few records because the complexity is O(n) or linear (go figure!).

You'll have to do research on the value of various structures and the knowledge of how your data is stored to get a better feel!

Comment: I got confused between binary search algorithm and B tree search algorithm . How many iterations will be there for both of them for 5 million records?

Comment: Well it depends on how your data is stored. As I said, if you data is 5 million rows of ordered integers, your iterations will be proportional to the log function. As far as I'm aware a binary search algorithm and a B tree search algorithm are the same thing.

Comment: b tree search algorithm : log(5000000)base2   and binary search algorithm : log(5000000). is it so ?

Comment: Ok a b tree should be less efficient if the data is completely sorted. I can't say by how much, but since it can have any number of child nodes, it has to be more complex.